# SQL (bigquery) - SUM continues values with start/stop DATETIME within time interval

Tags: sql, datetime, select, google-bigquery, sum

Given the following *Table 1* that represents continues drug administration in a steady rate:

| row | id | starttime | endtime | drug_total_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | 2163-04-13T03:00:00 | 2163-04-13T06:00:00 | 99 |
| 2 | 21 | 2163-04-13T16:00:00 | 2163-04-13T23:00:00 | 540 |
| 3 | 21 | 2163-04-14T02:30:00 | 2163-04-14T17:00:00 | 308 |
| 4 | 21 | 2163-04-14T17:00:00 | 2163-04-14T20:30:00 | 72 |
| 5 | 21 | 2163-04-14T20:40:00 | 2163-04-15T00:00:00 | 40 |
| 6 | 6 | 2163-04-14T17:00:00 | 2163-04-14T20:30:00 | 72 |
| 7 | 6 | 2163-04-14T20:40:00 | 2163-04-15T00:00:00 | 39.75 |
| 8 | 6 | 2163-04-15T00:00:00 | 2163-04-15T01:00:00 | 13.5 |
| 9 | 6 | 2163-04-15T01:00:00 | 2163-04-15T02:00:00 | 9 |

And *Table 2* that represents events with timestamps:

| row | id | event | event_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | 1 | 2163-04-14T17:30:00 |

**What is the most efficient way to sum administrated values to a specific id in a given time interval prior to the event?**

---

**For example:**
I want to sum a drug amount for a 24 hour interval before event id 1 (`pre_24_hours_drug`) -
The relevant rows in table 1 are 2-4 (per id and time range):

2. Only the partial amount between 17:00 and `endtime` (~424)
3. Whole amount (308)
4. Only the partial amount between `starttime` and 17:00 (~10)

the result should be:

| row | id | event | event_time | pre_24_hours_drug |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | 1 | 2163-04-14T17:30:00 | 742.5714286 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select t2.id, t2.event, t2.event_time,
  sum(t1.drug_total_amount 
    / timestamp_diff(t1.endtime, t1.starttime, second) 
    * timestamp_diff(
      least(t2.event_time, t1.endtime),
      greatest(timestamp_sub(t2.event_time, interval 24 hour), t1.starttime),
      second)
  ) as pre_24_hours_drug
from `project.dataset.table2` t2 
join `project.dataset.table1` t1
on t1.id = t2.id 
and t1.starttime < t2.event_time
and t1.endtime > timestamp_sub(t2.event_time, interval 24 hour) 
group by t2.id, t2.event, t2.event_time
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - the output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use a join to get all the matching rows.  The following should get all overlaps:

```
select t2.*, t1.*
from t2 join
     t1
     on t2.id = t1.id and
        timestamp_add(t2.event_time, interval -1 day) < t1.end_time and
        t2.event_time > t1.start_time;
```

Now the trick is to prorate the amounts and sum:

```
select t2.event, t2.event_time,
       sum(t1.drug_total_amount *
           timestamp_diff(second, 
                          least(t2.event_time, t1.end_time),
                           greatest(timestamp_add(t2.event_time, interval -1 day), t1.start_time)
                         ) /
           timestamp_diff(second, t1.start_time, t1.end_time)
          ) as drug_amount
from t2 join
     t1
     on t2.id = t1.id and
        timestamp_add(t2.event_time, interval -1 day) < t1.end_time and
        t2.event_time > t1.start_time
group by t2.event, t2.event_time;
```

Comment: Thank you! I think that in your last rows that's should be `t1.start_time < t2.event_time`  and `t1.end_time > t2.event_time-24`

Comment: @arielhasidim . . . I updated the logic in the answer.  It might be equivalent to what is in your comment.  But the one day has to *start* before the period in `t1` ends.  And it has to end after the one in `t1` starts.